# How to get the value from a category custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom field for categories called `featured` and it is a `checkbox` for `true or false`.

```
$catArray = array();
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $feat = get_field('featured', $term);
    echo $feat;
    if ( $feat ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        array_push($catArray, $category->cat_ID);
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve its `value` and if `true` I need to `echo` something otherwise `echo` nothing.

The above is outside the loop.

I also tried to check if the field is empty but as soon as I check it or uncheck it, it has a value (true/false) so it will always show once we click on it

```
$catArray = array();
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $fields =  get_term_meta( $category->cat_ID );
    if(!empty($fields['_featured'][0])) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        array_push($catArray, $category->cat_ID);
    }
}
```

I tried the following too

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $fields =  get_term_meta( $category->cat_ID );
    $feat = $fields['_featured'];
    if(!empty($fields['_featured'][0]) && $fields['_featured'][0]) {
        var_dump($feat);
        print "<pre>";
        echo $feat."<br>";
        print "</pre>";
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        array_push($catArray, $category->cat_ID);
    }
}
```

And it gives me the following even tho I have unchecked all of them

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "field_5bf5205ca3910" }
Array
Argomenti (this is a name and link)
array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "field_5bf5205ca3910" }
Array
Cammini (this is a name and link)
array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "field_5bf5205ca3910" }
Array
La mia casa (this is a name and link)
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox in acf fields returns empty when unchecked.
Try using the radio Buttons and use the Choices as...

```
true : True
false : False
```

Then check as a astring..
`if ( $feat === 'true' )`

Comment: Am i not checking for if !empty($fields['_featured'][0]) ?

Comment: it is not picking up true or false
                        `foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                            $fields =  get_term_meta( $cd->cat_ID );
                            $feat = $fields['_featured'];
                            if ( $feat === 'true' ) {
                                echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';

                            }
                        }`

Comment: see updated question where at the bottom I placed the latest code